# The generalization of Hartogs' Theorem

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I know a version of Hartogs' Theorem in the book *An introduction to complex analysis*(p 30) by Hormander, namely
[Hartogs' Theorem when K compact with complement being simply connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MOr4.png)

I also have learned another version in *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry I* (p34) by Voisin. [Hartogs' Theorem when $K=\{z_1=z_2=0\}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZrVC.png)

My question: are there any generalizations of Hartogs' Theorem, with respect to $K$ (i.e. we only change the condition of $K$, confining the stage in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ )?

Any clue is welcome. Many Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what kind of generalization you are looking for, but you might find this interesting https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.03425.pdf.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%27s_extension_theorem#Formal_statement) it is sufficient to suppose $G$ is open, and $G \setminus K$ is connected. However they do not give a direct reference.